# Analytics API, new microservice or integrate with existing API?

Tags: architecture, microservices

We run a hosted portfolio service of sorts, with an API (CakePHP, MySQL), and separate frontend applications (javascript) that connect with it. The API (let's call it the Content API) is pretty monolithic in that it deals with authentication, storing and retrieving all content, sending out emails, basically everything server-side. We have a small team and our service is relatively small (thousands of users). We are currently running on a single Amazon EC2 instance, but looking to scale in the near future.

We are about to build an analytics system, which will comprise of a front end showing fancy graphs, and an API storing events and providing data for the aforementioned graphs.

Now the dilemma I'm struggling with: shall I create a separate Analytics API, or integrate its functionality with our existing Content API?

I have been reading about the advantages of microservices, and since analytics is such a distinct feature, I'm inclined to think that it deserves having its own API. However...

The data we are dealing with is not too crazy. We are talking GBs not TBs. Also, the analytics data is pretty structured (event-type, datetime, user_id, content_id, that sort of stuff). Also, we will not be searching text strings. All this leads me to think a relational database is more suited than, say, elasticsearch. Since I already know MySQL, I'm inclined to use MySQL for Analytic as well.

Also, since I already know CakePHP, I'm inclined to use CakePHP for the Analytics API as well. Though I'm still open for perhaps a more lightweight PHP framework.

Now, as I mentioned, the Analytics API will need to store events (pageviews and such). But it will also need data from our Content API (usernames, filenames, etc). Furthermore, I want to use authentication, which is also handled by our Content API. So if our Analytics frontend makes a request to our Analytics API, the Analytics API will have to make one or multiple requests to our Content API before it can put together a reply. At the very least to authenticate the user, but also to gather parts of the data needed for the Analytics graphs.

One of the advantages of microservices that is often mentioned, is that you can work on them independently, adding and changing functionality, maybe move to a whole new platform. Another is scalability: you can scale one microservice without having to scale the other.

However, when one microservice requires data from another microservice (as is the case in my situation) aren't these advantages mostly negated? Whenever I change an endpoint on our Content API, I will need to think about whether that endpoint is being used by our Analytics API. No unittests to cover that. And when usage of our Analytics API grows, I cannot just scale up the Analytics infra because the Content API will also be hit more often.

So I'm wondering whether a monolithic approach wouldn't make more sense in our situation? Or are there benefits to the microservice approach I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is a typical scenario in any microservice implementation. And none of your thoughts are wrong. Yes these will be disadvantages ; which will mean more work and more latency because https rest api call will be much slower than call made inside JVM..

Also, you are right that it is NOT always true that micro-services can be maintained independently.. If one MS is calling other; automatically there is a dependency..

Having said all this, we all know people are moving to micro-services because of one BIGGEST Advantage... which is infinite Scale... If suppose u are Amazon.. you have to achieve scale at whatever cost .. which can be even higher latency numbers.. Then micro-service is the ONLY solution.. These days we have even 256 GB RAM boxes on cloud.. so until u reach Amazon level you should be able to handle scale..

But, if suppose for whatever reason your organization has decided Micro-services as the way to go forward.. Then this is the right time for u to develop Analytics in Micro-services... Because, always we will have lots to deliver..we will have so many feature releases in pipeline always.. we will never get time to re-engineer existing products into micro-services.. So, atleast whatever u develop new.. develop that as a micro-service.. This way your team also learns stuff and its not too much risk and optimal use of time.

This is based out of my personal experience.

Comment: and yes, it is perfectly fine to use MySQL for analytics.. don't fall into trap like others do who just use all fancy names for heck of it... Even today many big websites work on MySQL..

Comment: Thanks for your insights! Although obviously there are no right or wrong answers here, just various views and experiences, I'm gonna go ahead and accept yours :)